# How to sort DD-MM-YYYY dates linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have dates in a DD/MM/YYYY format, with the caveat that for days <10 dates are single digits.

Some example data is below:

```
name,date,time
DEF,1/02/2021,06:00
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,1/04/2021,05:50
```

I only want to sort by the date column. I find this challenging since the days part of the date value is variable in length.

Comment: 1) split the 2nd field on slash to extract individual day, month and year elements.
2) generate a string in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.
3) prepend the string to each record delimited by a tab.
4) sort the records.
5) remove the 1st column with `cut` command.

Comment: Cross site posting https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719017/how-to-sort-dd-mm-yyyy-dates-in-ascending-order-variable-date-length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to sort the date field (`[d]d/mm/yyyy`) directly within a comma-separated field (`sort` natively understands US `mm/dd/yyyy` style dates but not this international alternative). However, picking out that date field and reordering the fields as `yyyy-mm-dd` makes it much easier, and `sort` can handle this as a standard alphanumeric sort. The process of temporarily pulling out the primary sort key is known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Here you would sort the result, then throw away this first (temporary) field to regain the original unchanged data.

```
awk -F'[,/]' '{printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\t%s\n", $4,$3,$2, $0}' datafile | sort | cut -f2-

name,date,time
HIJ,31/01/2021,07:50
ABC,1/02/2021,05:50
DEF,1/02/2021,06:00
```

You can see the result of the intermediate process if you strip back either before or after the `sort` command.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk, you can make use of it's internal sorting functions:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; FS=","}
     {split($2,b,"/"); a[b[3]*10000 + b[2]*100 + b[1]]=$0}
     END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

More details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Split your data following the separators "," and "/" (using `awk`), you will end up with five columns:

```
DEF  1 02 2021 06:00
HIJ 31 01 2021 07:50
ABC  1 04 2021 05:50
```

Then, sort according to columns four, three and two numerically (`sort -k4,3,2 -n` or something similar).

You might decide to leave the data as they have been transformed (you'll up with this result):

```
HIJ 31 01 2021 07:50
DEF  1 02 2021 06:00
ABC  1 04 2021 05:50
```

... or you might want to put it back into the original formatting:

```
HIJ, 31/01/2021 07:50
DEF,  1/02/2021 06:00
ABC,  1/04/2021 05:50
```